# hokuyo model-based topic name

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello every body,
I am trying to use the Hokuyo sensor for a multirobot simulation. I would like to have the laser publishing on a different topic based on the model name. Is it possible?
I tried to edit the sdf gathered from
[laser tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins#Laser)
but it defines only a fixed topic.

Any suggestions?

Even on the basis of the namespace would work

Thanks
Andrea

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6052/hokuyo-model-based-topic-name/) by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Solved, more or less. When defining the tag topicName, omitting the initial '/' will tell the plugin to use the robot namespace.

```
  <topicName>laser/scan</topicName>
```

---

Originally posted by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) with karma: 72 on 2014-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0